# How can we set input type as textBox/CheckBox depending on the data retrieved from the collection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, meteor

My Requirement:
1. Get all the records from a collection and display each in an accordion.
2. For the records field i should check wheather it's a `string/boolean`.
3. If it's a `string/boolean` then I should get `textBox/checkbox` respectively.
**sample.txt**

```
<div class="container">
    {{#each listjobs}}
        <i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:30px;background-color:red;padding: 5px 10px;"></i>
        <button class="accordion">{{job}}</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul class="panel_elements">
                  {{params}}
                  <li><input type="submit" name="trigger" value="Trigger" /></li>
                  <li id="status">{{status}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

**My DB entry:** this fields will change for most of the documents inside the collection.

```
 "_id" : "8yfjmbMbv7KcNaKwz",
    "platform" : "abcd",
    "url" "http://<jenkins Address>/job/test/",
    "job" : "testing",
    "status" : "SUCCESS",
    "parameters" : [
            {
                    "name" : "DIRECTORY",
                    "value" : "def"
            },
            {
                    "name" : "BUILD_PROFILE",
                    "value" : "abc"
            }
    ]
}
```

**sample.js**

```
Template.trigger.events({
'click .accordion':function(){
    var jobId = this._id;
    Session.set('selectJob', jobId);
    var selectedPlayer =Session.get('selectJob');
    console.log(selectedPlayer);
    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
      acc[i].onclick = function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.maxHeight){
          panel.style.maxHeight = null;
        } else {
          panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        } 
      }
    }
},
});

Template.trigger.helpers({
'params':function(){
    var selectedJob = Session.get('selectJob');
    console.log(selectedJob);
    console.log(AddPipe.findOne({ "_id": selectedJob }));
    /*var param=AddPipe.findOne({ _id: selectedJob},{_id:0,parameters:1}).fetch();
    for(var i in param){

    }
    */
    return AddPipe.find({_id:selectedJob},{parameters:1}).map(function (c) {        
    return {label: c.parameters, value:c.parameters};
    });
},
```

Comment: You're basically asking people to write a fairly substantial amount of code for you. At least give it a shot first. Make helpers that give you the list of keys, then another that gives you a key type, etc... or just use the autoform package.

Comment: Sorry if u feel that way, I'm learning meteor and i need some work done ASAP, because i have to reach the goal within the deadline. I don't have the full understanding of meteor so for that reason I couldn't code it syntactically. I know the logic but writing in meteor is bit difficult for me at this point of time. I have updated the JS code for ur reference.@MichelFloyd

Comment: "I'm learning meteor" ... the more **you** code the more **you** will learn. What are the actual issues tou have with your current code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a couple of helpers `isBoolean` and `isString`, or a more general `typeIs`

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  isBoolean(value) {
    return typeof value === 'boolean';
  },
  isString(value) {
    return typeof value === 'string';
  },
  typeIs(value, type) {
    return typeof value === type;
  }
});
```

Then in your template, use an `if`

```
<div class="container">
    {{#each listjobs}}
        <i class="fa fa-close" style="font-size:30px;background-color:red;padding: 5px 10px;"></i>
        <button class="accordion">{{job}}</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <ul class="panel_elements">

                {{#if isBoolean recordsField}}
                  <li><input type="checkbox"></li>
                {{/if}}
                {{#if isString recordsField}}
                  <li><input type="text"></li>
                {{/if}}

                  <li><input type="submit" name="trigger" value="Trigger" /></li>
                  <li id="status">{{status}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Note: Because helpers like this are useful everywhere, it makes sense to make them available to every template using `Template.registerHelper`